# Go: Is *Var a "subclass" of Var?

Tags: go

taken from the go tour:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    f := MyFloat(-math.Sqrt2)
    v := Vertex{3, 4}

    a = f
    a = &v

    // v == Vertex != *Vertex -> exception
    a = v
}

type MyFloat float64

func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return float64(-f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

However, when turning `func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64` into `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64`, the code compiles:

```
package main

import (
    "math"
)

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func main() {
    var a Abser
    f := MyFloat(-math.Sqrt2)
    v := Vertex{3, 4}

    a = f

    // Since *Vertex != Vertex, this shouldn't compile, should it?
    a = &v

    a = v
}

type MyFloat float64

func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return float64(-f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

Why does the second example run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `*T` is not a subclass of `T`, but `*T`'s [method set](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) will inherit the methods of `T`:

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T).

So if `T` conforms to a particular interface, then so will `*T`.  That is why you could assign a `*Vertex` value to an `Abser` variable in your example.